# If $E_i\hookrightarrow E_{i+1}$, $(x_n)$ is bounded in $E_1$, $x_n\to z$ in $E_3$ and $x_{n_k}\to y$ in $E_2$, then $x_n\to z$ in $E_2$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $E_i$ be a Banach space s.t. $E_i$ is continuously embedded into $E_{i+1}$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq E_1$ be bounded and s.t. $x_n\to z\in E_3$ in $E_3$ and $x_{n_k}\to y\in E_2$ in $E_2$ for some subsequence $(n_k)$.

Why can we conclude that $z\in E_2$ and $x_n\to z$ in $E_2$?

Clearly, since the embedding of $E_2$ into $E_3$ is continuous, $x_{n_k}\to y$ in $E_3$ and this should immediately yield $z=y\in E_2$. But how do we conclude that $x_n\to z$ in $E_2$?

Comment: As gerw points out, this is not correct and you should *disaccept* (if this word exists) the answer. In many concrete cases on analysis, the is some compactness that helps. For example, your clain is correct if the embedding of $E_1$ into $E_2$ is compact.

Comment: @Jochen In the application that I've got in mind, $E_1$ is actually compactly embedded into $E_2$. How does the desired claim follow then?

Comment: There is no strictly coarser Hausdorff topology on a compact set. Therefore, the topologies of $E_2$ and $E_3$ coincide on every bounded subset $B$ of $E_1$ (because its closure in $E_2$ is compact and the $E_3$-topology is coarser and Hausdorff).

Answer (score 2):

This is not true.

Let
$E_1 = E_2 = \ell^1$
and
$E_3 = \ell^\infty$. For each $n \in \mathbb N$, we define the sequence $x_{2n} = 0$
and
$$
x_{2n+1}(i)
=
\begin{cases}
\frac1{n} & \text{for } i \le n, \\ 0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, the sequence $x_n$ satisfies the requirements (the convergent subsequence is $x_{2n}$), but it does not converge in $E_2$.

Comment: @Jochen Thank you for your answer. In the application that I've got in mind, $E_1$ is actually compactly embedded into $E_2$. Does the desired claim follow then?